# NSCoding in Swift not archiving data properly?

Tags: ios, swift, archive, nscoding

I'm relatively new to iOS development in general, but I'm coding this app.

I have custom objects "Semester", "Course", and "Assignments". Semesters contain arrays of courses and courses contain arrays of assignments. I'm able to properly archive the semester and course information, but for some reason the assignment information can't be read.

Semester:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = ""

    super.init()

    if let archivedName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String {
        name = archivedName
    }
    if let archivedCourses = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "courses") as? [Course] {
        courses = archivedCourses
    }
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(courses, forKey: "courses")
}
```

Course:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = ""
    super.init()

    if let archivedName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "courseName") as? String {
        name = archivedName
    }
    if let archivedAssignments = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "assignments") as? [Assignment] {
        assignments = archivedAssignments
    }
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "courseName")
    aCoder.encode(assignments, forKey: "assignments")
```

Assignment:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = ""
    self.grade = 0
    self.weight = 0
    super.init()

    if let archivedName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "assignmentName") as? String, let archivedGrade = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "assignmentGrade") as? Int, let archivedWeight = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "assignmentWeight") as? Int {
        name = archivedName
        grade = archivedGrade
        weight = archivedWeight
    }
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "assignmentName")
    aCoder.encode(grade, forKey: "assignmentGrade")
    aCoder.encode(weight, forKey: "assignmentWeight")
}
```

I'm not sure why but the assignment details can't be read when I try to decode the object.

Comment: decoderObject have an special method to decode Ints

Comment: Did my answer help you? any feedback is appreciate, thanks

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Can you accept my answer then? is the gray checkmark thanks

Comment: Done! Sorry, just joined the website.

Comment: ok, not problem, welcome to this community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Usually decode `Int` like this

```
if decoder.containsValue(forKey: "teamNumber"){
    self.teamNumber = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "teamNumber")
}
```

translated to your issue will be like this, change the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`method of your `Assignment` class

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    self.name = ""
    self.grade = 0
    self.weight = 0
    super.init()

    if let archivedName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "assignmentName") as? String{
      self.name = archivedName
    } 

    if decoder.containsValue(forKey: "assignmentGrade"){
        self.grade = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "assignmentGrade")
    }

    if decoder.containsValue(forKey: "assignmentWeight"){
        self.weight = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "assignmentWeight")
    }

}
```

Hope this helps